# How do I create equal angles in this hex grid in R?

Tags: r

I've created a hex grid over the city of Alexandria, VA with unequal angles in R. I'd like for all angles within the grid to equal the same value. How could I fix the code to return a nicer grid. Thanks.

```
study_area <- getData("GADM", 
                      country = "USA", 
                      level = 2) 

virginia <- study_area[study_area$NAME_1 =="Virginia", ]  
alexandria <- virginia[virginia$NAME_2 == "Alexandria", ]

plot(alexandria, col = "grey50", bg = "light blue", axes = TRUE)
text(-77.13,38.85,"Study Area:\nAlexandria")

size <- 0.0025
hex_points <- spsample(alexandria, type = "hexagonal", cellsize = size)
hex_grid <- HexPoints2SpatialPolygons(hex_points, dx = size)
plot(alexandria, col = "grey50", bg = "light blue", axes = TRUE)
plot(hex_points, col = "black", pch = 20, cex = 0.5, add = T)
plot(hex_grid, border = "orange", add = T)
```

I understand this may be projection issue, which I'm not great with in R. Projection of hex grid reads, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

https://github.com/Bikingman/Transportation_Planning/blob/master/Rplot01.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the projection seems to have fixed the problem.

```
study_area <- getData("GADM", 
                      country = "USA", 
                      level = 2) 

virginia <- study_area[study_area$NAME_1 =="Virginia", ]  
alexandria <- virginia[virginia$NAME_2 == "Alexandria", ]

alexandria <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=WGS84 +units=mi +no_defs") %>% 
  spTransform(alexandria, .)

plot(alexandria, col = "grey50", bg = "light blue", axes = TRUE)
text(-77.13,38.85,"Study Area:\nAlexandria")

size <- .3
hex_points <- spsample(alexandria, type = "hexagonal", cellsize = size)
hex_grid <- HexPoints2SpatialPolygons(hex_points, dx = size)
plot(alexandria, col = "grey50", bg = "light blue", axes = TRUE)
plot(hex_points, col = "black", pch = 20, cex = 0.5, add = T)
plot(hex_grid, border = "orange", add = T)
text(195.75,2673,"Study Area:\nAlexandria")
```

[Fixed hex grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88yVf.png)